# collection counter pretty formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code in order count the amount of instances occur in a log file. But i am trying to print it out a little nicer to read, but i can't figure it out. Here is what i have so far

```
for key, count in collections.Counter(traffic_list).most_common():
    print ('{}: {}'.format(key,count))
```

And i can't seem to format the first {}

When i print out the collection it looks like this:

```
(‘192.168.10.5’, ’10.10.10.10’, ‘http’): 76
(‘192.168.10.6’, ’10.10.10.10’, ‘http’): 34
(‘192.168.10.7’, ’10.10.10.11’, ‘http’): 32
(‘192.168.10.8’, ’10.10.10.10’, ‘http’): 21
```

I am trying to get it to look like this:

```
Source: 192.168.10.5 -> Destination: 10.10.10.10 -> Servive: http -> Count: 76
```

But i can't get it look like that

Comment: What have you tried to get it to look like that? I presume you don't expect your provided code to have that output.

Comment: No, i tried this but it just errors out to the screen, print ('src, dst, serv = {}: {}'.format(src,dest,serv,count)) but i just get an error of src is not defined

Comment: I can't figure out if there is even a way to format that first {}

Comment: Actually it wasn't copied, i wrote it out in notepad on mac, and it comes out like that

Comment: Your key is a tuple of (three) strings, e.g. `(‘192.168.10.5’, ’10.10.10.10’, ‘http’)`. So your print call needs to handle that tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for key, count in collections.Counter(traffic_list).most_common():
    print ('Source: {} -> Destination: {} -> Service: {} -> Count: {}'.format(key[0], key[1], key[2], count))
```

Comment: Wow C0DY thanks, exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Passing all the subcomponents of the key as `*key` is more elegant, as per @AbhijithAsokan's deleted answer.